# Getting the Size of a NSImage allocated with NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, macos

```
NSImage *testImages;
NSURL *testImageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///foo/testImage.png"];
NSData *imageData = [testImageUrl resourceDataUsingCache:NO];
testImages = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData ];
```

How do I get the NSSize of testImages. In the debugger I can read it with from the _NSSize property but [testImages size] return (0,0)

I need it determine if it's a landscape or portrait image before I do various transformations.

This worked but I don't know why?

```
NSArray *representation = [testImages representations];
NSImageRep *repOne = [representation objectAtIndex:0];
int width = [repOne pixelsWide];
return width;
```

Comment: `-[NSURL resourceDataUsingCache:]` was deprecated in Mac OS X v10.4. What’s your target OS?

Comment: Have you checked whether `testImages` is `nil` after `-initWithData:`?

Answer (score 0):

In **NSImage** class, We do have property, which give us the size of image in [NSImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
- (NSSize)size
   NSSize size = testImages.size;
```

Comment: For the sake of accuracy, there is no `size` declared property in `NSImage`.

Comment: NSIamge and UIImage both have a size property.  @Bavarious, what are you saying?

Comment: @Black I’m saying that a declared property is not the same as a getter (and optionally a setter) method.

Comment: I still consider myself new to objective-C, so I am not sure what you are saying? But looking at the [NSImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) I see the *- (NSSize)size* method.  For [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) I see the size property.

Comment: @Black The official documentation clearly indicates when ‘x’ is a declared property, which is not the case of `size` in `NSImage`. The header file is another source of information as well — there is no `@property … size;` in `@interface NSImage…`. From the Objective-C runtime perspective, an enumeration of the properties declared in `NSImage` wouldn’t list `size` — in fact, it wouldn’t list any property.

Answer (score 0):

> "...but [testImages size] return (0,0)"

Always consider whether, at some point in your code, some method or call returned `nil` where you weren't expecting it. Then walk your way back up the code to figure out where your code (or your assumptions) went wrong.

```
NSURL *testImageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///foo/testImage.png"];
NSData *imageData = [testImageUrl resourceDataUsingCache:NO];
NSImage *testImages = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData ];
NSSize size = [testImages size];
```

If for some reason the `URLWithString:` call failed, it would return `nil`. Sending the `-resourceDataUsingCache:` message to `nil` would basically result in `nil` (it's just ignored). Trying to create an `NSImage` with `nil` passed in for the data parameter will return `nil`. And sending the `-size` message to `nil` will basically result in `nil`, which will equal a size of `{0, 0}`.

So, double-check to make sure your messages weren't just being sent to nil.

Just another note, but you usually use `+fileURLWithPath:` when creating file-based `NSURL`s and `+URLWithString:` when creating other types of URLs.